# How to output different phrases depending on time of day, without using an Excel document?

Tags: vba, datetime, time, outlook

I do a process 3 times a day. On my emails to signify what processes I have done, I write AM, Noon, or PM. Is there a way in Outlook VBA to accomplish this in a template?

I would need to have this input a dynamic set of characters (AM, Noon, or PM) in the Subject and the Body, based off the time of day.

I want it to show as AM before 10 AM, as Noon between 10 AM and 2 PM, and as PM" after 2 PM.

Is this feasible or am I better off using a different method?

I have an AM, Noon, and PM template, but it would be great if I had one dynamic template.

My AM code:

```
Sub CreateNewMail()
    Dim obApp As Object
    Dim NewMail As MailItem

    Set obApp = Outlook.Application
    Set NewMail = obApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    With NewMail
         .Subject = "Docs " & Format(Date, "m.d.yy") & " AM"
         .To = "Mr. Nobody"
         .Body = "Attached are the docs for " & Format(Date, "m.d.yy") & " AM."
         .Display
    End With

    Set obApp = Nothing
    Set NewMail = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

*Work with [Time function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/time-function) it Returns a Variant (Date) indicating the current system time. and  [Select...Case Statement (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/select-case-statement) which Runs one of several groups of statements, depending on the value of an expression.*

---

*Example*

```
Option Explicit
Sub CreateNewMail()

    Dim info As String

    Select Case True

        Case Now <= TimeValue("10:00:00 AM")
            info = " AM" 
            Debug.Print info

        Case Now > TimeValue("10:00:00 AM") And Now < TimeValue("02:00:00 PM")
            info = " Noon" 
            Debug.Print info

        Case Now >= TimeValue("02:00:00 PM")
            info = " PM" 
            Debug.Print info

    End Select

End Sub
```

*[Debug.Print Method prints on Immediate window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debug.print?view=netframework-4.8)*

---

*To use it in your code see below example*

```
Option Explicit
Sub CreateNewMail()

    Dim info As String ' - < added

    Select Case True

        Case Now <= TimeValue("10:00:00 AM")
            info = " AM" ' - < added
            Debug.Print info

        Case Now > TimeValue("10:00:00 AM") And Now < TimeValue("02:00:00 PM")
            info = " Noon" ' - < added
            Debug.Print info

        Case Now >= TimeValue("02:00:00 PM")
            info = " PM" ' - < added
            Debug.Print info

    End Select

    Dim obApp As Object
    Set obApp = Outlook.Application

    Dim NewMail As MailItem
    Set NewMail = obApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    With NewMail
         .Subject = "Docs " & Format(Date, "m.d.yy") & info ' - < added
         .To = "Mr. Nobody"
         .Body = "Attached are the docs for " & _
                              Format(Date, "m.d.yy") & info ' - < added
         .Display
    End With

    Set obApp = Nothing
    Set NewMail = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: So how exactly would I incorporate this into the code for my subject and body of a VBA email template? I am currently having to use .HTMLBody because I want bullets in my template. Where and what would I input into my current code? Currently, where there is an " AM" is where I would want there to be a dynamic time function kind of like what I see above.